# EventBus, register and registerSticky method

Tags: android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

I use greenrobot EventBus library to send data between two fragments in my android app and I want to know what is the diffeence between `register(Object b)` method and `registerSticky(Object object)` method?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`EventBus` allows you to post events that are "sticky" and by that `EventBus` understands events that "stick to the eventbus" for future access.

If you post a *normal* `event` when there are no `subscribers` registered at the moment of sending, this `event` will be discarded.

You can post a *sticky* `event` though, even if there are no `subscribers` to receive that at the moment, and it won't be discarded (unless there is another sticky `event` posted in the future). When a `subscriber` registers with `registerSticky` the delivery of the **last** sticky `event` is also triggered.

Comment: Can I use `resgisterSticky` instead of `register` all time?

Comment: Although `registerSticky` acts like regular register (and triggers the delivery of last `sticky` `event`) I think it should be avoided as long as you don't see a serious case for using `sticky event`

Comment: @blipinsk Why avoid? Please elaborate... Can I mix the two register and registerSticky/post and postSticky?

Comment: @powder366 Sure thing you can mix the two of them. As long as you see a case for that and as long as you don't mean registering the same object to the same `EventBus` instance with both methods (`register` and `registerSticky`) at the same time. Because in that case mixing those two doesn't make any sense (only `registerSticky` would give the same result).

Comment: @powder366 You should avoid using `registerSticky` (for a **regular** registering to `EventBus` - without a serious case for `registerSticky`) because it could lead to extremely hard to debug situations. Imagine you have some sort of short-life event (which could for example represent a reaction to user click). It would be possible for you to receive an old event (that has been posted with `postSticky` a relatively long time ago) and you would treat it as an event that has been posted right now.

Comment: This text should replace this "crap" http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/ so people like me would understand it :)